# Call GUI function from another GUI

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I have GUI1 that opens GUI2.
I want GUI2 to execute a function from GUI1.

This [link](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/16538-calling-a-function-in-one-gui-from-another) shows how to execute a callback, but i want to execute a function.
Thanks

Comment: If your function needs to be called in multiple scripts, you may consider save the function in a separate file.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a handle to that function and save it somewhere where it can be assessed.

e.g. in the GUI1 opening function (where hObject is GUI1 figure object/handle):

```
func.myFun1=@myFun1;
func.myFun2=@myFun2;
setappdata(hObject,'fun_handles',func);
```

then, in GUI2, you can recover the handles with `func=getappdata(GUI1_figure,'fun_handles');`, where `GUI1_figure` is GUI1 figure object. The figure object can be either saved when the GUI is greated (e.g. if GUI2 is always created from GUI1, pass the object as an argument and save it somewhere) or found with something like `findobj(0,'-depth',1,'Tag','tag_of_GUI1_figure')`